# Array is empty when fetching data in template post axios – vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i try to fetch data from an array returned with vuejs script. i displayed data in script and everything is well. in created function, the value array is empty. but with template. the array is empty and not returned null.

```
export default {
        name: 'attribute-values',
        props: ['attributeid'],
        data() {
                return {
                   values: [],
                    value: '',
                    price: '',
                    currentId: '',
                    valueTest:'',
                  addValue: true,
                  key: 0
                }
            },
    methods: {
        loadValues() {
            let attributeId = this.attributeid;
            var self = this;
               self.valueTest='a test';
            axios.post('/admin/attributes/get-values', {
                id: attributeId
            }).then (function(response){
                self.values = response.data;
                console.log(self.values);
                this.values=self.values;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });           
            console.log(this.values);
            }
        },
        created :function() {   
        this.loadValues();
    }
    }
```

and this is the template

```
<tr v-if="values.length==0"><td>No items founds</td></tr>
                    <tr v-for="valuee in values" :key="valuee.id">
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ valuee.id }}</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ valuee.value }}</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">{{ valuee.price }}</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%" class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

this is the output of the array returned from created function:

[image]